# Flutter animate sliver size change

Tags: flutter, flutter-sliver

On Flutter, is there something similar to [`AnimatedSize`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedSize-class.html) for slivers? I want to animate a sliver's size change.

**What I Tried**

When I just wrap a sliver with `AnimatedSize`, Flutter throws these errors:

> A RenderAnimatedSize expected a child of type RenderBox but received a child of type RenderSliverToBoxAdapter.

> _AnimatedSizeState is a SingleTickerProviderStateMixin but multiple tickers were created.

Used this code:

```
class Testingyeye extends StatefulWidget {
  const Testingyeye({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Testingyeye> createState() => _TestingyeyeState();
}

class _TestingyeyeState extends State<Testingyeye> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Testing"),
      ),
      body: CustomScrollView(slivers: [
        SliverToBoxAdapter(
          child: AnimatedSize(
            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
            curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
            child: SliverList(delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
              (context, index) {
                return Text("hiii");
              },
            )),
          ),
        )
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

Ps I could find `SliverAnimatedOpacity`, which animates the opacity of a sliver. I couldn't find the one for animating the size of the sliver tho.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `SliverList` inside non-sliver widget like `AnimatedSize` here, instead use Column.

```dart
SliverToBoxAdapter(
  child: AnimatedSize(
    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
    curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
    child:Column(
      children: List.generate(4, (index) => Text("A")),
    ) ,
  ),
)
```

You can wrap `AnimatedSize` with `SliverToBoxAdapter` .

```dart
SliverToBoxAdapter(
  child: AnimatedSize(
    duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
    child:   
  ),
)
```

Comment: Ye I did that, and I got the error “A RenderAnimatedSize expected a child type …”. I couldn’t find a way to put a sliver as the child of the AnimatedSize widget.

Comment: Can you include sample widget that will reproduce the same issue, on my test case, it is working fine

Comment: I've just added my code into the question.

Comment: Check update one, youcant have slivers inside non-sliver AnimatedSize

Comment: Yea I mean that would definitely work, but then Flutter wouldn't clip out the children that are not currently shown on the screen.

Comment: Wait thinking about what I just said, it might be super complicated to achieve this as we cannot know the size of a sliver as easy as a box.

Comment: This how sliver widget works, you can create custom sliver widget too and place on CustomScrollView

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247154/discussion-between-shawn-and-yeasin-sheikh).